# Why the download and upload speed in an application like WhatsApp is different?

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns, web-applications, server

The download speed of documents, images, videos etc is faster as compared to the upload speed no matter how fast the net connection is.

The above statement was made in general but tried specifically in WhatsApp.

Is there any specific advantage or technical reason for it?

Comment: no matter how fast the net connection is....ISP always provide less upload speed than download speed.....thats why

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for this.

One of the most significant is that whatsapp will compress the assets before uploading to save data, this takes time. Also less bandwidth is used for uploads as compared to downloads.

Comment: " Also less bandwidth is used for uploads as compared to downloads."

That's what, is there a specific reason why bandwidth for uploads is kept less that that of download.

Answer (score 0):

The download is everytime faster than the upload. In Whatsapp all assets like documents, images, videos etc. will be compressed (Arvindsinc2) said it. 
The disadvantage is the quality from this assets. The compression for videos and images is so strong that you just can use this files for your phone. Images that you send via whatsapp are not suitable for printing or similar projects.

The video files are very compressed. Looking at the TV is almost impossible. On the handy but enough

The reason for the compression is that the bandwidth on mobile terminals is kept low.